# Проверять дерево ключей в словаре

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь

```
dict1 =   {
        "value": {
            "test": {
                "name":{
                    "age":"30"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Нужно забирать элемент словаря, при этом какого то ключа может не быть, в этом случае заменять на дефолтное.
Все это нужно делать в одну строку!

```
dict1 =   {
            "value": {
                "test": None
            }
        }
```

Сделал такой вариант, но не првильно, есть еще варианты?

```
dict1.get("value").get("test").get("name").get("age") or "null"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = {
    "value": {
        "test": None
    }
}

print(((((dict1.get("value") or {}).get("test") or {}).get("name") or {}).get("age") or {}) or 'null')
```

```
null
```

Comment: Можно проще записать. У get есть второй параметр, get возвращает его значение, если ключ не найден.

Comment: @insolor обратите внимание, что значение в словаре может быть None. Тогда второй аргумент get() не поможет. Я проверял перед тем, как предложить это решение

Comment: Понял, согласен

Comment: Но правда такой способ не поможет, если там не None, а, например, число (не 0), тогда вылетит AttributeError. Так что в принципе способ со вторым параметром get вполне рабочий, а для остального делать обработку исключений.

Comment: @insolor условие "Все это нужно делать в одну строку!" не предполагает обработку исключений

Comment: Это не важно. Исключение можно обработать и уровнем выше где-то, так что формально останется одна строка. Я к тому, что использование `dict1.get("value") or {}` вместо `dict1.get("value", {})` обрабатывает только небольшую группу специальных случаев (falsy значение), но не обрабатывает всех остальных возможных случаев (не словарь и не falsy значение - число, список, строка и т.д.), так что в принципе можно использовать get со вторым параметром, не пытаясь обработать какие-то гипотетические случаи.

Comment: @insolor можно использовать тернарный if с проверкой типа и, если это не словарь, возвращать словарь

Answer (score 2):

Вариант1:

```
s = dict1.get("value",{}).get("test",{}).get("name",{}).get("age",{})
print(s)
```

Вариант с изголениями:)

```
getv = lambda d, val:  d.get(val,{})
s = getv(getv(getv(getv(dict1,"value"), "test"), "name"),"age")
print(s)
```

Comment: 1. Вы проверяли первый вариант на втором примере с None? 2. "Все это нужно делать в одну строку!"